# "Hello, world!" example for DevExpress QuantumGrid?

Tags: delphi, grid, components, devexpress

I successfully installed the latest [QuantumGrid](http://devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/) from DevExpress, but I've never worked with this grid before, and I don't know how to get started. I find that the HLP file isn't really a tutorial, and the demos are so rich to the point where I can't get started quickly and see if QuantumGrid fits my needs.

Would someone happen to have a really basic example on how to create a small, non-DB-bound, non-hierarchized, but user-editable grid to host a couple of columns and fill the grid with a few rows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a grid on a form, then delete its default `GridView` and add a `TableView`. Add a few columns to TableView and then associate your GridLevel with this new view. Place a button on form and add this code to its click handler.

```
cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.BeginFullUpdate;
try
  cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.RecordCount := 3;
  cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.SetValue(0,0,'Data1');
  cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.SetValue(1,0,'Data2');
  cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.SetValue(2,0,'Data3');
finally
  cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.EndFullUpdate;
end;
```

`RecordIndex` corresponds to the row index and `ItemIndex` corresponds to the column index. I hope this helps you to get started.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a table
   view(gridlevel->create view->table)
2. Create columns(double click cxgrid
   and add)
3. Set property(inner controls like
   DateEdit) if you want. default
   property is textedit)
4. You can insert/delete via
   TableView.DataController.Insert/TableView.DataController.Delete*
   or use navigator(View->OptionsView->Navigator)

You should look at demos("quantumgrid directory"\Demos\Delphi), demos are more helpful than help files :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the help. For those interested in getting started with this grid object, here (what I think) are the steps presented above:

(idursun)

1. Add a TcxGrid object to the form
2. In the Structure object in the IDE, right-click on cxGrid1, and select "Delete View"
3. Right-click on cxGrid1, and select "Editor"
4. Click on the "Views" tab, click on "Add View...", and select "Table" in the drop-down list
5. In the "Columns" tab on the right, click on "Add", and add a few columns
6. Still in this dialog box, go back to the "Structure" tab on the left
7. Right-click on cxGridLevel1, and choose "Select View" to associate the Level with this new TableView. Close the dialog
8. In the form, add a button, and paste this code to its Click event:

   cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.BeginFullUpdate;
   try
     cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.RecordCount := 3;
     cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.SetValue(0,0,'Data1');
     cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.SetValue(1,0,'Data2');
     cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.SetValue(2,0,'Data3');
   finally
     cxGrid1TableView1.DataController.EndFullUpdate;
   end;

(barism)

1. Add a TxGrid object to the form
2. Within this new cxGrid1 object in the form, right-click its cxGrid1Level object, and select "Create View > Table"
3. In the Structure object in the IDE, right-click on cxGrid1, and select "Editor..."
4. In the Columns tab on the right, click on Add to add a couple of columns. Close this dialog
5. To add data to the grid, either write code, or right-click on cxGrid1 and select "Edit Layout and Data"